# Why does ProgressIndicator not work in the following case?

Tags: list-manipulation, monitoring

Consider a table:

```
Monitor[Module[{}, 
   Table2Temp[\[Theta]S_] := 
    Table[{\[Theta]S, mS, 10^\[Theta]2, 
      NIntegrate[
       Exp[-10^\[Theta]2 \[Theta]S*mS^3*10^2*x], {x, 0, 10000}]}, {mS,
       0.03, 2.03, 0.05}, {\[Theta]2, -15., -3., 0.02}]];, 
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[mS, {0.03, 2.03}], mS}, " "]]
Table2[\[Theta]S_] := Flatten[Table2Temp[\[Theta]S], {2, 1}];
```

When launching `Table2` for particular values of `\[Theta]S` I found that the progress indicator does not work. This is somehow related to the := used in the definition of the table. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
table2[ts_] := 
 Module[{\[Theta]S = ts}, 
  Table1 = Monitor[
    Table[{\[Theta]S, mS, 10^\[Theta]2, 
      NIntegrate[
       Exp[-10^\[Theta]2 \[Theta]S*mS^3*10^2*x], {x, 0, 10000}]}, {mS,
       0.03, 2.03, 0.05}, {\[Theta]2, -15., -3., .02}], 
    Row[{ProgressIndicator[mS, {0.03, 2.03}], mS}, " "]]; 
  Flatten[Table1, {2, 1}]]
table2[1]
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
Module[{}, 
  Table2Temp[\[Theta]S_] := 
   Table[{\[Theta]S, mS, 10^\[Theta]2, 
     NIntegrate[
      Exp[-10^\[Theta]2 \[Theta]S*mS^3*10^2*x], {x, 0, 10000}]}, {mS, 
     0.03, 2.03, 0.05}, {\[Theta]2, -15., -3., 0.02}]];
Table2[\[Theta]S_] := 
 Monitor[Flatten[Table2Temp[\[Theta]S], {2, 1}];, 
  Row[{ProgressIndicator[mS, {0.03, 2.03}], mS}, " "]]
```